# ¿Cómo agregar librerías en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación y voy a utilizar una librería, pero no sé en que carpeta debo de agregar el **jar** o de que forma agregarlo al proyecto para poder utilizarlo en la aplicación.
Estoy utilizando **Android Studio 2.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ruta correcta es el directorio `/libs` dentro del proyecto (si no existe se debe crear), con agregar el .jar dentro del directorio `/libs`, es suficiente para registrar un .jar al proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Solamente tienes que copiar el jar en la siguiente ruta:

```
C:\Users\nombre_usuario\AndroidStudioProjects\nombre_proyecto\lib\app\libs
```

De esta forma podrás usarlo en tu aplicación.

Comment: Esta ruta no es común para los proyectos Android. Y no es lib\app\libs debe ser en la raiz del proyecto.